# MySql Query for Hierarchical no of childrenwish parent grouping

Tags: mysql

[image: Here is my 2nd Example Table]

[image: This is Another Example table]

now i want to show parent id on every lebel who has one child and who has two child and who has no child and i want to do it level wish
like if i want to search for level1 and no of children is 1 then it should return
level1 details which has only one child in level2
my table name is level_count

Comment: In your table what is parent and children?

Comment: please see my table, here in every level have some data and who is the parent of his next level... like who has in level1 is the parent of level 2 and who has in level2 is the parent of level3 ans so on...upto level9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44709301/8188370
Join the table with a subquery that counts the number of rows for the parent, and only select the ones with the count you want.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.level1 AS Parent, a.level2 AS Child
FROM yourTable AS a
JOIN (SELECT level1, COUNT(DISTINCT level2) AS children
      FROM yourTable
      GROUP BY level1) AS b
ON a.level1 = b.level1
WHERE children = :child
```

Replace `:child` with the number of children you're trying to match.

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/YVVO68555)

Using `COUNT(level2)` instead of `COUNT(*)` will ignore the rows where `level2` is `NULL`, so it won't include `A100`.