# Get all record of Level 1 which has only specified number of values in Level 2

Tags: mysql

```
 level1 | level2  |level3 
--------|---------|--------
 A100   | NULL    | NULL
 A101   | B200    | C300
 A101   | B200    | C301
 A101   | B200    | C302
 A101   | B201    | C310
 A102   | B209    | NULL
 A103   | B211    | NULL
 A103   | B213    | NULL
 A103   | B214    | NULL
 A104   | B240    | NULL
```

i have this table and i want this following out put
if i choose `child=1` for level 1 then output should be

```
 Parent | Child
--------|---------
 A102   | B209
 A104   | B240
```

if i choose `child=2`for level 1 then output should be

```
 Parent | Child
--------|---------
 A101   | B200
 A101   | B201
```

if i choose `child=3`for level 1 then output should be

```
 Parent | Child
--------|---------
 A103   | B211
 A103   | B213
 A103   | B214
```

how can i acchive this in mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the table with a subquery that counts the number of rows for the parent, and only select the ones with the count you want.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.level1 AS Parent, a.level2 AS Child
FROM yourTable AS a
JOIN (SELECT level1, COUNT(DISTINCT level2) AS children
      FROM yourTable
      GROUP BY level1) AS b
ON a.level1 = b.level1
WHERE children = :child
```

Replace `:child` with the number of children you're trying to match.

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/YVVO68555)

Using `COUNT(Column2)` instead of `COUNT(*)` will ignore the rows where `Column2` is `NULL`, so it won't include `A100`.

Comment: 0 134 02:32:50 SELECT a.*
 FROM Level_Count  AS a
 JOIN (SELECT level1, COUNT(*) AS children
       FROM Level_Count 
       GROUP BY level1) AS b
 ON a.level1 = b.level1
 WHERE children = :level2 Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':level2' at line 7 0.000 sec

Comment: 02:36:22 SELECT a.level1 AS Parent, a.level2 AS Child FROM Level_Count AS a JOIN (SELECT level1, COUNT(level2) AS children       FROM Level_Count       GROUP BY level1) AS b ON a.level1 = b.level1 WHERE children = :child Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':child' at line 7 0.000 sec

Comment: its shows the error  at this point =>"WHERE children = :child"

Comment: That's a placeholder that you replace with the number of children you're trying to find.

Comment: I added `DISTINCT` to the query to match your updated data.

Comment: if i get children=2 then out put shown right but when i get children=1 it shows no record

Comment: yes sir,i see your example ..... but here in my work bench its not working for  children=1, and thank you so much sir for given me your valuable suggesion

Comment: Maybe you don't have any parents like that in your data. It works with the data you posted.

Comment: Are you sure you changed `COUNT(level2)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT level2)` like I did in my query?

Comment: sir I was working with similar data and do every thing which you suggest